# Chamar função pelo OnClick passando parâmetros

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando chamar uma função ao clicar em um link, onde é passado um parâmetro que será utilizado em uma requisição Ajax.

Esta requisição retornará resultados que serão adicionados a uma div.

O código do link com a chamada da função é a seguinte:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="Iniciais" onclick="pBuscaFichaEmergencia('<?php echo $Letra; ?>');"><?php echo $Letra; ?></a>
```

O código da função é:

```
function pBuscaFichaEmergencia(){
    var Iniciais = $('#Iniciais').val(); 

    console.log("INICIAL: " + Iniciais);

    if (Iniciais) {
        var url = 'pBuscaFichasLetras.php?Iniciais='+Iniciais 
        $.get(url, function(dataReturn) {
            $('#resp-emergencia').html(dataReturn);  
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que devia acontecer?

Comment: Olá @Sergio, ao passar o valor do parâmetro da variável "Iniciais" para a página "pBuscaFichasLetra.php" faria a consulta e devolveria uma resposta formatada em uma tabela html posicionada na div resp-emergencia, mas não consigo passar o valor dessa variável.

Comment: Qual é a parte que não funciona? no servidor ou no browser?

Comment: O que não funciona é no Browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você ira passar as letras pelo PHP desta maneira

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="Iniciais"  onclick="pBuscaFichaEmergencia('<?php echo $Letra; ?>');"> <?php echo $Letra; ?>  </a>
```

Você precisa declarar sua função  recebendo um parametro

```
function pBuscaFichaEmergencia(Iniciais )
```

E não será necessário utilizar jquery para pegar o valor

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Marco Vinicius Soares Dalalba, consegui resolver meu problema.